# Why is a change of carrier on Greyhound no transfer?

Tags: buses, greyhound

The below schedule is an example of a Greyhound trip. It says there are zero transfers on the route.

[image: Example schedule Greyhound]

However, when looking at the schedule, I see that there is a change of carrier and schedule. Does it mean you have to physically change buses, or do they only change the sign? It probably has to do with crossing the border, but what happens there?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I did a quick search and whilst the display you are looking at does not specifically show a transfer, it does indicate a change of carrier, which is a good indication that you will have to disembark and board a new coach.

When I checked the greyhound website via my mobile it shows the stop in Buffalo to be a transfer. (Different display to the one you found as I'm on my tablet)

[image]

Hope this helps

Comment: Any idea why I got three tickets? One to NY - Syracuse, one Syracuse - Buffalo, one Buffalo - Toronto? Especially the first one.

Comment: @Bernhard: This should really be a new question.

Comment: @NateEldredge But I saw you already found: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/37025/is-20-minutes-of-transfer-time-enough-at-the-buffalo-greyhound-station I didn't want to put to many at once ;)

Comment: @NateEldredge See http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/37047/why-did-i-receive-3-tickets-for-a-single-transfer-greyhound-trip