# Is 20 minutes of transfer time enough at the Buffalo Greyhound station?

Tags: usa, short-connections, greyhound, buffalo

Recently, I bought a bus ticket for Greyhound, which gives me 20 minutes at the Buffalo bus terminal (see [Why is a change of carrier on Greyhound no transfer?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/35057/why-is-a-change-of-carrier-on-greyhound-no-transfer) ).

I am a bit worried now, will this 20 minutes be enough to make the transfer? What is the worst case scenario?

Comment: I have no knowledge of the locations or carrier BUT 20 minutes is tight when human factors may prevail.Telling the driver in advance and having your bag available at the front of the luggage compartment and having the driver "bought in" can help. If the bus is not overly full he may allow you to carry all your luggage onboard - something I try and do where possible when "abroad".

Comment: **If your inbound bus is coming from Canada, book a different connection**.  Buses from Canada are frequently late due to the border, where the bus is held until ALL passengers are cleared.  If there is a lot of traffic or if any passenger is causing doubts, everyone is late.  I had a 2-hour Buffalo transfer once, coming from Toronto, and only caught my connection because the train was late as well.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know about Buffalo specifically, but with the exception of a few gigantic cities, bus stations are usually not large places.  Often they are just one big room with a dozen or so places outside for buses to park.  I can't imagine it will take you more than a few minutes to find your next bus and board.

So the only risk is that your incoming bus might be late.  Unfortunately, I don't know of any way to estimate that risk - it would depend on where you are coming from, traffic, and how conservatively Greyhound has set the schedule.  I am not sure that they publish on-time statistics for their routes.

If your inbound bus is late and you miss the connection, Greyhound should put you on the next bus headed for your destination.  That's the worst case scenario.  You'll have to check the schedule to see how long a wait that might be - it could be as little as an hour or so, or as long as a day or two.

Comment: I found there is one bus leaving three hours later.

Comment: Luggage should be considered, leaving the bus light is easy, leaving it while having a checked in luggage is something else especially when only 20 minutes is all you got.

Comment: @MeNoTalk: That's a good point, and I'm not sure about Greyhound, but often "claiming checked luggage" means "wait another minute or two for the driver to get off, pull your suitcase out from the luggage compartment, and dump it on the curb for you to take".

Comment: @NateEldredge true, not sure about if it takes a minute or two, it wont be the only piece of luggage, and no one knows if it will be the first...