# Why did I receive 3 tickets for a single-transfer Greyhound trip?

Tags: usa, greyhound, syracuse

I've recently booked a Greyhound trip (see [Why is a change of carrier on Greyhound no transfer?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/35057/why-is-a-change-of-carrier-on-greyhound-no-transfer))

I will be traveling from New York City to Toronto, which has a [transfer in Buffalo](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/37025/is-20-minutes-of-transfer-time-enough-at-the-buffalo-greyhound-station). For the first leg, however, I received two separate tickets. One NYC to Syracuse, and one Syracuse to Buffalo. The scheduled number is however the same. Why did I receive three tickets in total, and not two?

Comment: NY->Toronto with transfer in Buffalo...  Why on earth did you do that?

Comment: @Karlson I am considering to buy a plane ticket instead ;)

Comment: @Karlson: What's wrong with it?

Comment: @Karlson I think most, perhaps all buses have a transfer in the border city of Buffalo, perhaps related to the border crossing.  The same for Chicago to Toronto which has a transfer in Detroit.

Comment: @NateEldredge Megabus offers no transfers and faster run.

Comment: @Karlson http://us.megabus.com/JourneyResults.aspx?originCode=123&destinationCode=145&outboundDepartureDate=10%2f12%2f2014&inboundDepartureDate=&passengerCount=1&transportType=0&concessionCount=0&nusCount=0&outboundWheelchairSeated=0&outboundOtherDisabilityCount=0&inboundWheelchairSeated=0&inboundOtherDisabilityCount=0&outboundPcaCount=0&inboundPcaCount=0&promotionCode=&withReturn=0 How do I see it is a direct connection?

Comment: @gerrit Chicago yes.  But the border crossing doesn't have anything to do with this.  NY->Montreal doesn't require a transfer.  Far more likely the union rules related the length of the travel.

Comment: @Bernhard Those are direct routes.  you don't transfer buses the places listed are just stops.  If I am not mistaken the Route Number if M21.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It actually is odd that the carrier chose to do this but it's quite simple though not very well explained on the Greyhound Website.

When you look at [New York Trailways(Purchase Tickets)](http://secure4.gatewayticketing.com/trailwaysny/shop/ViewItems.aspx?Merchant=Transportation&CategoryGroupExternalID=6&CategoryExternalID=33) site it becomes clear.  Instead of one connection in Buffalo, you actually have 2 in Syracuse and Buffalo even though the bus schedule number/route number doesn't change in Syracuse.

Comment: Your link appears to be broken.

Comment: @Bernhard Try now.

Comment: I am not really sure what I am looking at there?

Comment: Select Purchase Tickets.  It doesn't show the schedule without it.

Answer (score 3):

I used to have a similar situation with a different New York bus company (Short Line / Coach USA).  I would travel from Ithaca to New York City.  Some trips had a transfer in Binghamton and some did not; however, I was always issued two tickets: one from Ithaca to Binghamton and another from Binghamton to NYC.

The reason in that case was that the tickets were not actually attached to a particular departure; they were valid on any bus between those points during a certain time period (I think 30 days).  So even if I was planning to take a bus that ran express and did not even stop in Binghamton, I was issued two tickets in case I decided instead to take a different bus that needed a transfer.

Comment: http://transportation.fs.cornell.edu/coach/schedule/default.cfm  Probably more expensive then Coach but more convinient.

Comment: @Karlson: Yeah, I used to take the Cornell bus also sometimes (I no longer live in Ithaca).  It was more comfortable and slightly faster, but about 60% more expensive.  It also tended to sell out quickly at popular times (Coach USA could usually add extra buses as needed to meet demand).  Usually my decision was based mainly on which bus fit my schedule better.